# how to access the response value outside done function

Tags: javascript, php

```
var response = [];

    $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "{{url('api/xyz')}}",
    })
    .done(function( res ) {
        var rr;
        if(res.status == 'success'){
            rr = res.data;
            response.push(rr);
        }
    });


    console.log(response);
```

Not getting exact response

getting

Array[0]length: 0__proto__: Array[0]concat: concat()constructor: Array()copyWithin: copyWithin()entries: entries()every: every()fill: fill()filter: filter()find: find()findIndex: findIndex()forEach: forEach()includes: includes()indexOf: indexOf()join: join()keys: keys()lastIndexOf: lastIndexOf()length: 0map: map()pop: pop()push: push()reduce: reduce()reduceRight: reduceRight()reverse: reverse()shift: shift()slice: slice()some: some()sort: sort()splice: splice()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()unshift: unshift()Symbol(Symbol.iterator): values()Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): Object__proto__: Object

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Anything you want to do with the ajax response should be done in the .done function, like pushing it to an array (you got that part) and then logging the array (oops).

Comment: how to access the response value outside done function

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous call , your console.log executed before you push the data , try console.log after you push into array

```
var response = [];

    $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "{{url('api/xyz')}}",
    })
    .done(function( res ) {
        var rr;
        if(res.status == 'success'){
            rr = res.data;
            response.push(rr);
           console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: how to access the response value outside done function

Comment: you can return a promise and resolve when request completes